# Скомпилировать стороннюю библиотеку в отдельный javascript файл

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Как скомпилировать внешнюю библиотеку и собрать в отдельный от основного проекта  js файл.
Конфигурационный файл для компиляции typescript кода:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Файл конфигурации webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  mode: 'development'
},
```

Сторонняя библиотека располагается в `/lib/Phaser/`

Answer (score 0):

Обычно сторонние библиотеки распространяют и подключают при помощи NPM. И хранятся в репозитории как отдельный проект. Если авторы библиотеки этого не сделали, то вы можете проделать это самостоятельно.

Как вариант, можно хранить стороннюю библиотеку в репозитории основного проекта, но компилить её отдельно от проекта (отдельный tsconfig, отдельный webpack config, отдельный скрипт `npm run build-phaser`).

К сожалению, webpack и компилятор ts - это не про выделение библиотек из проекта, а наоборот про слияние библиотек в один проект.